# How to Insert datetime index of pandas DataFrame into mongodb as a field with isoDate type

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
like:

```
              open  high  close   low    volume     amount
 date                                                    
 2015-11-27  8.10  8.16   7.35  7.34  37877648  294274400
 2015-11-26  8.03  8.44   8.16  8.00  45933600  378897088
 2015-11-25  7.95  8.03   7.99  7.89  21255886  169172176
 2015-11-24  7.95  8.18   8.04  7.85  24808112  199120256
 2015-11-23  8.24  8.29   7.95  7.93  29176848  236019264
```

df.index

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-27', '2015-11-26', '2015-11-25', '2015-11-24',
           '2015-11-23', '2015-11-20', '2015-11-19', '2015-11-18',
           '2015-11-17', '2015-11-16',
           ...
           '2014-12-12', '2014-12-11', '2014-12-10', '2014-12-09',
           '2014-12-08', '2014-12-05', '2014-12-04', '2014-12-03',
           '2014-12-02', '2014-12-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'date', length=193, freq=None)
```

How to insert df into mongodb with a date.index field in `isoDate` format but not datatime64[ns]/timestamps? .

Answer (score 3):

I've been bothered for a long time, but I finally found a way to do it.
It depends on the way we insert mongod.
I used to insert mongod in this way:

```
records = json.loads(DataFrame.T.to_json()).values()
collection.insert_many(records)
```

We need to understand that this approach will convert DataFrame time into datatime64[ns]/timestamps.

```
print records[0]
{u'dtime': 1407076151000L,u'olddtime': u'2014/8/3 14:29:11'}
```

We can see that it saves time as numberlong and DateTime as string.So we need change records:

```
for row in records:
    row['olddtime'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['olddtime'], "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then we print it:

```
{u'olddtime': datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 3, 14, 29, 11), u'dtime': 1407076151000L}
```

Finally we do this:

```
collection.insert_many(records)
```

That's OK!

Comment: if i want to overwrite the entry in mongodb if it is same then how to do that.I thing we suppose to do update with upsert option but how to frame it ??